# Apache HttpClient Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Peer Not Authenticated

Tags: java, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to configure `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` to work with https. This is the client configuration:

```
TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new DummyTrustManager() };

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(scheme);

ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParameters);
```

This is the code of `DummyTrustManager`:

```
public static class DummyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And when I send request, I get

```
 `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to adjust the `TrustStrategy`:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType) {
        return true;
    }
};
SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(acceptingTrustStrategy, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
...
```

see a full example at: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl